# Can't install AdDuplexWP8 package from nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, nuget

I'm trying to download [AdDuplexWP8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdDuplexWP8) package but this error appears:

> Could not install package 'AdDuplexWP8 2.8.0.4'. You are trying to
> install this package into a project that targets
> 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any
> assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more
> information, contact the package author.

I think the problem isn't from the package, but from my side!. I see the same error appears for some other packages too.

How can I install that package? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be using older NuGet. Try to install newer one from [here](https://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/112815).